# How to get ID Parameter in url also in java

Tags: java, html, web-applications

How to get ID Parameter in my url

https://example.com/?id=8281

how to get **id= value** in html

GET ID  IN URL

also anyone tell for applications

Comment: Cant get url in html. You have to use some script. Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters

Comment: You should try yourself and when you faced problem share it here and the community is ready to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a query parameter, you can get it with plain javascript like this.

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myParam = urlParams.get('myParam');
```

reference -> [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Actually this is what I was looking for, thank youuu!!!